# Completely remove Java 9 from Ubuntu 17.10

Tags: java, ubuntu

I did a fresh Ubuntu 17.10 installation a while ago and needed to install Java to build react-native apps on my PC. So I was able to install Java 9 in the manual way by downloading it from the Oracle official site.

Now when I run `java --version` I get

```
java 9.0.4
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 9.0.4+11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 9.0.4+11, mixed mode)
```

and when I run `javac --version` I get

```
javac 9.0.4
```

And then I followed official react docs and created a react app.
Then when I try to run it on an android emulator I got an error and I opened a [github issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/17688#issuecomment-359297203)

Seems like it's an issue with Java 9 . So now I need to completely remove java 9 from my PC and install Java 8. How can I completely remove Java 9 from my Ubuntu 17.10 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an ubuntu question and not an android question, but you need to get a list of the packages that are responsible for java 9 and uninstall them.

```
apt list --installed | grep -i jdk
```

then call apt-get remove with the package for java 9

```
apt-get remove java9-sdk.xyz
```

You can also modify your configuration using the following:

```
sudo update-alternatives --config java
```

And outlined here:

https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-java-with-apt-get-on-debian-8#managing-java

Comment: Maybe that's why I get so many downvotes. I'll post this on Ubuntu forum.

Thanks for clarifying.

Comment: @ThidasaParanavitharana You get downvotes because the are literally thousands of pages explaining how to do this, meaning you didn't even searched the issue.

Comment: @sfratini yes, there is. I followed more than 10 and tried to remove it. But even after trying those when I run `java -version` it gave me java 9 as the result. Anyway I couldn't remove that but I was able to set java 8 as the default library by following [this](https://www.vultr.com/docs/how-to-manually-install-java-8-on-ubuntu-16-04)